# Query Builder error when accessing property in template

Tags: symfony, eloquent, twig

I am working on a symfony app and we're using eloquent to manage database interactions and I am running in to a really odd issue.

I am injecting a 'session' variable to the view and on the twig template, I am dumping it out:

```
        {"id":1,"old_id":null,"course_id":21,"location_id":1,
"date1":"2019-06-05","start_time1":"08:30:00", "end_time1":"00:17:00","date2":null,"start_time2":null,"end_time2":null,"...
```

Note, the **date2** variable is there and it is null.

In the twig template, when trying to access this date2 property, I get the following error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::date2()").
```

Note, this is the code that is triggering the above error:

```
{% if session.date2 %}
{% endif %}
```

Also tried:

```
{% if session.date2 is not null %}
{% endif %}
```

Also tried:

```
{% if session.date2 is defined %}
    {% endif %}
```

Any idea why this is? I am out of ideas and appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: How are you dumping the variable?

Comment: Like this: ```{{ session }}```

Comment: That will trigger the `__tostring()` method of your object, it's strange that your are passing a `builder` instance towards twig. Did you not fetch the actual row from the database first?

Comment: I picked up this project and thats hows it is currently set up, to pass in builder object to the view. Thats a good point you're making..

Comment: Thank you, it doesn't make sense to pass builder, thats probably the issue.

Comment: If you are using `session.date2` in twig it willl first look for a public property `date2` and after that for the public getter `getDate2`, that is why you are getting that error.

Comment: date2 and the rest of the properties are protected and non null columns don't throw an error... isn't that odd?

Comment: Yeah can't figure out why you get that output, but you could try `session.first().date2`

Comment: I added a public getDate2() that returns the protected property $this->date2 and now it works! Whats most odd is I don't need to do that for any non null columns.

Comment: Adding first(), resulted in the same error, by the way.